# Facebook App Review Process apparently makes impossible to any Vuforia + Unity + FB Plugin app to be public

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, vuforia, review

I have a problem with an iOS App using Vuforia and Unity with a valid Facebook Plugin, the problem comes not in the plugin itself (that works properly), but in the Facebook Review process to make the App public and let all users in.

Today doing tests on the finished app, I realized that when using a valid Facebook Plugin  (or any other Facebook implementation) with an user that is not the Facebook User Owner of the app (in this case me), Facebook request you to go to "App Status and Review" to click on:

"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? YES| NO". This was traditionally allowed to be clicked, but today it's not. The option is not allowed.

"Yes" would make the app accessible to everybody. But this option (YES) is not available a priori, because the App needs first to pass a Facebook review process, in particular a Facebook Review Process to determine if the App is in agreement with its policy. (So we have to pass two reviews: Apple and then Facebook)

The problem here is apparently it's impossible to a Vuforia-Unity App to pass this process. To pass the Facebook Review process you need to send them your App in one of this two available format:

1. sending the id to Apple Store App (that is impossible to do, you can not send App Store an unfinished app), or
2. sending them a file containing a Simulated Build (using Terminal to build the project in xcodebuild -arch i386 simulatorXX).

None of this available options provided by Facebook are possible to Unity-Vuforia, technically, so it's technically impossible to obtain the approval of the App. This is because:

1. App Store is not going to pass an App that is not working (the FB button won't work, so App Store is not going to allow us finish the process and they will reject). So you cannot provide an AppStore-id to the Facebook Review team.
2. As far as Facebook only receives "Simulated Builds" it would be impossible to a Vuforia Unity App to be accepted, this is because when you are using Unity + Vuforia you can not build a simulated build, is incompatible. So is impossible to fit this requirement.

My questions here to you to try to solve this are:

1. Did you have this problem and solved it previously?
2. Is there anyway to avoid the Facebook review?
3. Do you know how long does it take to Facebook do the review?
4. Can you think in anything else to try to solve this?

PS: I am using a Neatplug plugin to connect to Facebook.

Comment: I have just noticed this as well, im going to contact Facebook to see what we can do.